# Is there a way to silence output from dependencies in Rust?

Tags: rust

One of my dependencies has a few `println!` scattered around that seem to be debugging artifacts and I'm trying to find a way to suppress them, but haven't had any success so far.

I've been looking at macros, and tried putting one inside the function where the imported struct is instantiated but with no success, likewise when giving it a global scope.

```
macro_rules! println {
    ($($rest:tt)*) => { }
}
```

Is there any way I can use a macro to target an external crate, or any other solution short of forking the codebase?

Comment: `println!` simply writes to `stdout()`. There currently is no official built-in way to redirect that, but [there is a crate](https://crates.io/crates/gag). It's not exactly great but you could use `gag` to redirect stdout before calling the dependency and restore it afterwards. Alternatively, you could study and copy [the stdlib's](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.32.0/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L622-L667) (which is probably roughly what gag does). The stdlib's function is a private implementation detail used by the test system to capture stdout/stderr.

Comment: The best solution would probably be to file an issue or even create a PR for that dependency. Libraries in general should not print to stdout. So likely someone just forgot to remove those statements. The library's maintainer surely will appreciate you telling them.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a PR and will use `gag` in the meantime!

Comment: Debugging outputs in dependencies should use the `log` crate which can be filtered out by an application. (e.g. `log::trace`, `log::debug`, `log::error` etc.)